# Flow does not show for some users on custom lightning page

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, permissions

I have a custom lightning page that is set as the default for all users. However, the flow that is supposed to appear does not appear for the users.

- They have permission to run flows.
- It does show up for system administrators
- It updates a field on the record that the custom page points to

Also, the flow does update a field. Must the user have permission to edit that field for the flow to work?

Comment: Yes. The field must be accessible to the users. If the field is hidden, it would impact the component visibility . Related:https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000a21FQAQ

Comment: No luck on that. I am using an external service in the flow as well as named credentials for the external service. Does that matter?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the way I had to solve this was by unchecking a box. There is a little arrow next to the flow with a dropdown to 'edit access'.

The SF docs say that:

> Control user permission to run flows via:
>
> The “Manage Flows” permission The "Run Flows" permission The Flow User
> field on their user detail page If Override default behavior and
> restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets is selected for
> an individual flow, access to that flow is given to users by profile
> or permission set

I had the 'override' checked so it was not using the normal behavior. As soon as I unchecked the box everything worked.